# Why do I need to set an alias to my projection if it's optional?

Tags: nhibernate, castle-activerecord

I'm reading the [documentation](http://knol.google.com/k/fabio-maulo/nhibernate-chapter-13-criteria-queries/1nr4enxv3dpeq/16#13(2E)7(2E)(C2)(A0)Projections(2C)_aggregation_and_grouping) about DetachedCriteria. The documentation clearly shows that setting an alias for your projection is optional. However, whenever I omit the alias my model properties contain no data. Here are my two test models.

```
[ActiveRecord("INCIDENT")]
public class Incident : ActiveRecordBase<Incident>
{
    [PrimaryKey(PrimaryKeyType.Native, "INCIDENT_ID", ColumnType = "Int32")]
    public virtual int IncidentId { get; set; }

    [Property("CREATION_DATETIME", ColumnType = "DateTime")]
    public virtual DateTime? CreationDatetime { get; set; }

    [BelongsTo("CAUSE_CD")]
    public virtual Cause Cause { get; set; }
}

[ActiveRecord("CAUSE")]
public class Cause : ActiveRecordBase<Cause>
{
    [PrimaryKey(PrimaryKeyType.Native, "CAUSE_CD", ColumnType = "String")]
    public virtual string CauseCd { get; set; }

    [Property("CAUSE_DESC", ColumnType = "String", NotNull = true)]
    public virtual string CauseDesc { get; set; }
}
```

Here is what I use to query the database.

```
DetachedCriteria incidentCriteria = DetachedCriteria.For<Incident>("i")
.SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
   .Add(Projections.Property("i.IncidentId"))
   .Add(Projections.Property("i.CreationDatetime"))
)
.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<Incident>());
IList<Incident> incidents = Incident.FindAll(incidentCriteria);
```

Both projections properties do not get populated unless I set an alias. So my question is, why is the alias optional? I'm sure I'm simply missing something else. But if I put a random alias (e.g. abc) it'll return an error saying that it could not find property "abc" in the Incident class. Fair enough, I add the appropriate alias to match my property names. And voila! My properties are now property being populated.

Now comes the issue of when I want to query a lookup table. I add

```
.Add(Projections.Property("c.CauseDesc"), "CauseDesc")
```

to my ProjectionList and append

```
.CreateCriteria("i.Cause", "c")
```

But now it complains that it can't find "CauseDesc" from my Incident model.

What am I missing from this whole criteria ordeal?

Update:
The following code

```
IList<Incident> results = sess.CreateCriteria<Incident>("i")
    .SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
        .Add(Projections.Property("i.IncidentId"), "IncidentId")
        .Add(Projections.Property("i.CreationDatetime"), "CreationDatetime")
        .Add(Projections.Property("c.CauseDesc"), "CauseDesc")
    )
    .Add(Expression.Gt("i.IncidentId", 1234567))
    .CreateAlias("Cause", "c")
    .List<Incident>();
```

This does create a valid query (I checked it with a profiler) but it seems to be having issues populating my generic list. It gives me error "The value \"System.Object[]\" is not of type \"oms_dal.Models.Incident\" and cannot be used in this generic collection.\r\nParameter name: value". However, all works fine if I don't use a projection but then it selects 50+ fields which I don't want. Does that mean I'm forced to use a DTO in this circumstance?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify the projection property name like...

```
.Add(Projections.Property("i.IncidentId"), "IncidentId")
```

also, in general you do not project into the same domain object. You should create an incident dto like...

```
public class IncidentDTO  
{
    public int IncidentID { get; set; }
    public DateTime CreationDatetime { get; set; } 
}
```

and then...

```
.SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
   .Add(Projections.Property("i.IncidentId"), "IncidentId")
   .Add(Projections.Property("i.CreationDatetime"), "CreationDatetime")
)
.SetResultTransformer(Transformers.AliasToBean<IncidentDTO>());
```

If you want Incidents matching some criteria (not a DTO), then don't set projections/resulttransformer. Instead you simply do something like this...

```
IList<Incident> incidents = session.CreateCriteria<Incident>()
    .CreateAlias("Cause", "c")  //now you can access Cause properties via `c.`
    .Add(Restrictions.Eq("c.CauseDesc", "some cause")) 
    .List<Incident>();
```

See how the root criteria object doesn't need an alias. If it helps, I only use CreateCriteria for the initial object. If I need to reference child objects, I use CreateAlias.

Comment: About your last example, I keep getting error "The value \"System.Object[]\" is not of type \"oms_dal.Models.Incident\" and cannot be used in this generic collection.\r\nParameter name: value" when I set a projection. Please look at my updated answer.

Comment: Yes, if you set the projection you must use a DTO. Projections are NOT used to control the loading of properties in a domain object. They are used to project data into a DTO for display purposes.